# Can Humax HG100R-L2 router's ethernet port be used for a bridge?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, bridge, bridge-router

I am trying to set up a bridge network from router 1 to router 2 to expand my home wifi.

Both routers are the [Humax HG100R-L2](http://www.humaxdigital.com/gw/products/product.php?gid=524&pid=1) router which has two Gigabit Ethernet(RJ45) ports. A photo of the ports are shown below (ignore red annotation) [image: Humax HG100R-L2]

I had intended to connect an ethernet cable from router 1 to router 2. Are these ethernet ports bidirectional or can they only be used as outputs? Alternatively, is there another way of expanding my wifi using this second router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to bridge anything.

Disable DHCP and firewalling on the secondary router and assign it a different static IP(it should be 192.168.0.1 now, set it to .1.200 say). Then connect the two together over ethernet, job done.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a go, but are you sure the ethernet ports are can accept input?

Comment: Ethernet is by its very nature a bidirectional protocol

Comment: Why then are some ethernet ports labelled WAN and others LAN? Also what is the linking of routers called if it is not called a bridge?